# Washing machine stops mid cycle, buttons stop working, works again after an hour or two

Tags: repair, washing-machine

My washing machine stops working mid-cycle, sometimes after a few minutes. After it stopped, the buttons will no longer work, and if I wait a while (sometimes 10 minutes, sometimes 2 hours), it will start again and finish the cycle. I think it depends on the cycle how often it stops, although I'm not certain that is the case.

When it has stopped, the buttons will not work, and even a power-cycle doesn't help.

I checked the intake and all the tubes, all seem fine. I cleaned the filter, and the electronics look fine as well(by just looking at them).

The model is a `WF90F5E5U4W`, but I think the electronics might be from a different model (I bought it from a second hand shop).

Comment: Sounds like a thermal relay is tripping.  Usually a overheat is the cause, something gets too hot.  Some have a manual reset button.    If you are handy, some time on google can lead to repair or would need an appliance repair person to check it out.

Comment: Did you try the Samsung "smart check"  function/app?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did check the "smart check" function, but that seems to only work if the washing machine already shows an error (so pretty useless). I looked for a thermal relay @crip659, but I couldn't find it near the motor(where I was expecting it).